# how to fix featureCounts in miniconda (Linux) with error "featureCounts: invalid option -- 'r'"

Tags: terminal, miniconda

featureCounts was called under minconda in Linux subsystem on a Windows 10 computer.

```
  featureCounts -a /mnt/d/.../__.txt -F SAF -readExtensions3 200 -o ___.tsv -O file1.bam file2.bam file3p.bam file4.bam file5.bam file6.bam file7.bam file8.bam
```

This always results in an error message

```
    featureCounts: invalid option -- 'r'

    Version 2.0.1

    Usage: featureCounts [options] -a <annotation_file> -o <output_file> input_file1 [input_file2] ...

    ## Mandatory arguments:

      -a <string>         Name of an annotation file. GTF/GFF format by default. See...
```

And then reprinting the required and optional arguments for featureCounts function.

Does anyone know what does the error message "invalid option --'r'" mean? And how can I fix it?

Is there any difference between calling featureCounts in command prompt (or Terminal on Mac) and calling it in Linux/miniconda3?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you mistyped option name, it should be `--readExtension3` with two dashes in front of it and without 's' in the end. I had a similar problem with `--fraction` which led me here!